# Need to optimize my code that moves cells based on a string

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I am using the following code to combine lines of text.  The first line has no space, then a random number of lines below have a space in the 2nd character.  I move those lines to the row without the space, and to the right of the previous cell, then check the next cell down.  The code functions perfectly, but is very slow.  And i am running a Gen 1 i3 3.2Ghz with 8GB of RAM and Excel 2010 64-bit, so its not the system. However, the production system this will run on is a Core2 Duo 2.5-3Ghz with 3.2GB RAM available, so slower, and running Excel 2007 32-bit.  **UPD:** Screen updating and Calculation are off during this process.

Can anyone help to optimize it?  Example lines are below.  If it seems fast for you, just duplicate the data about 40,000 times.  My files contain about 90k lines each.  When finished, they combine to about 20k.  Massaging of the data is done before and after this process, but this is the killer.  As always, thanks in advance!!

```
Range("d1").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    i = ActiveCell.Value
    If Mid(i, 2, 1) = " " Then
        ActiveCell.Cut
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        CutCopyMode = False
    Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If   
Loop
```

**Example cells:**

```
10/1/2013   1:27:02 AM  [501014 ]CODELINE_INDICATION_MSG 192.168.013.212 606.1.01 (9781)  RX  38 bytes
10/1/2013   1:27:02 AM  [501014 ]  97 81 29 00 38 00 EA 23 4A A3 55 A1 73 4A 5A 1A
10/1/2013   1:27:02 AM  [501014 ]  14 A2 A2 00 2E 02 02 12 8B 03 00 08 08 01 00 01
10/1/2013   1:27:02 AM  [501014 ]  10 51 00 01 00 11
10/1/2013   1:27:03 AM  [501014 ]CODELINE_INDICATION_MSG 192.168.013.212 606.1.01 (9781)  RX  38 bytes
10/1/2013   1:27:03 AM  [501014 ]  97 81 29 00 3A 00 EA 23 4A A3 55 A1 73 4A 5A 1A
10/1/2013   1:27:03 AM  [501014 ]  14 A2 A2 00 2E 02 02 12 8B 03 00 08 08 01 00 01
10/1/2013   1:27:03 AM  [501014 ]  10 51 00 01 00 11
10/1/2013   1:28:59 AM  [501014 ]CODELINE_RECALL_MSG 192.168.013.254:0000  RX  26 bytes
10/1/2013   1:28:59 AM  [501014 ]  00 00 26 00 B2 02 AE 73 4A 5A 1A 14 A2 A2 23 4A
10/1/2013   1:28:59 AM  [501014 ]  A1 31 A2 00 2C 02 02 12 48 03
10/1/2013   1:28:59 AM  [501014 ]INT_L3_ATCS  010.1.13 (28d)  TX  29 bytes
10/1/2013   1:28:59 AM  [501014 ]  02 8D 25 00 98 00 AE 73 4A 5A 1A 14 A2 A2 23 4A
10/1/2013   1:28:59 AM  [501014 ]  A3 55 A1 00 3A 02 02 12 48 03 00 00 08
10/1/2013   1:28:59 AM  [501014 ]INT_L3_ATCS  010.1.13 (28d)  TX  29 bytes
10/1/2013   1:28:59 AM  [501014 ]  02 8D 25 00 98 00 AE 73 4A 5A 1A 14 A2 A2 23 4A
10/1/2013   1:28:59 AM  [501014 ]  A3 55 A1 00 3A 02 02 12 48 03 00 00 08
10/1/2013   1:29:00 AM  [501014 ]CODELINE_INDICATION_MSG 010.150.100.050 010.1.13 (28d)  RX  38 bytes
10/1/2013   1:29:00 AM  [501014 ]  02 8D 68 00 1E 00 EA 23 4A A3 55 A1 73 4A 5A 1A
10/1/2013   1:29:00 AM  [501014 ]  14 A2 A2 00 30 02 02 12 8B 03 00 08 08 01 00 01
10/1/2013   1:29:00 AM  [501014 ]  10 51 00 01 00 3D
```

Comment: Turn off screenupdating and set calculation to manual at the top of your sub.  Don't forget to set calculation back to auto when done (screenupdating will reset itself)

Comment: I should have note:  I've already done that.  But, thanks!  Anything more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 sec for 160k rows:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim tmp
    Dim arr, r As Long, numR As Long, maxW As Long, w As Long
    Dim arrOut(), rwOut As Long, colOut As Long

    'read info from columns A-D
    With ActiveSheet
        arr = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
    End With
    numR = UBound(arr, 1)

    'Find how "wide" the output array needs to be
    ' could skip this if you know the max possible width...
    maxW = 0
    w = 0
    For r = 1 To numR
        If Mid(arr(r, 4), 2, 1) = " " Then
            w = w + 1
        Else
            If w > maxW Then maxW = w
            w = 0
        End If
    Next r
    'resize output array
    ReDim arrOut(1 To numR, 1 To maxW + 4)

    rwOut = 0
    colOut = 5

    'populate the output array
    For r = 1 To numR
        tmp = arr(r, 4)
        If Mid(tmp, 2, 1) = " " Then
            If rwOut = 0 Then rwOut = 1 'in case first "non-space" line is missing
            arrOut(rwOut, colOut) = tmp
            colOut = colOut + 1
        Else
            rwOut = rwOut + 1
            arrOut(rwOut, 1) = arr(r, 1)
            arrOut(rwOut, 2) = arr(r, 2)
            arrOut(rwOut, 3) = arr(r, 3)
            arrOut(rwOut, 4) = tmp

            colOut = 5
        End If
    Next r

    'put output array onto worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(numR, maxW + 4).Value = arrOut

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: updated to account for keeping content in columns A-C

Comment: It seems the max it will ever be is 4 columns, and I do have data in A:C.

Comment: W.O.W.  You did it!!  With one exception.  The data in A:C remains.  I would like to delete the row that the moved cell came from, then examine next row.

Comment: A little unclear - you need to remove all data from columns A-C, or do you need to keep the A-C data associated with the "non-space" lines?

Comment: The reason for wanting to delete the entire row is that cells A-C for each set of 3 or 4 lines have timestamps, etc. that all need to stay with the combined line.  The array is currently moving all the data to the top and leaving the timestamps in place, disconnecting the data from its stamp.  Otherwise, its beautiful!

Comment: A little clearer:  Ex: Row 1, non space and rows 2-4, space.  All 4 rows have the same data in columns A-C.  Row 5, non space, new data in A-C.  I'll Include the in the sample text above.

Comment: +1! Masterpiece!  I would upvote, but although I have earned enough rep points, SO says I don't have enough.  Thanks VERY much. About 3 seconds for all NINETY THOUSAND lines.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Tim, do you have a good resource I could look at for building array solutions such as this one?  I have more code that would perform better as an array, but I'm not sure how to go about them.  Need more training.  (Working wonderfully, BTW.)

Comment: @SyteCyer - nothing specific I can point to: if really comes down to 1. Pulling the data from the sheet to an array, which is quite simple: just assign the value of the range to a variant variable.  2. Work with the resulting 2-D array using loops based on UBound() to tell you the size of the array in each dimension.  3. Drop the modified (or newly-created) array back to a worksheet by assigning the Value of a range to the array.   If you have specific problems you run into then you should post them as a new question and I'm sure you'll get help here.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to load the range into an array and do the changes and then spit them back out to the worksheet after, but sticking with your logic, you could replace your while loop with something more like this:

```
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    i = ActiveCell.Value
    If Mid(i, 2, 1) = " " Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count - 7).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
    Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop
```

This will simply move the value over without having to select cells, cut and paste, etc.

Hope this helps move you in the right direction.

Comment: Doing all the steps I want and working faster than mine, but slower than the Array.

Comment: If I were you, I'd go with an array solution, quite honestly - It's much better programming and will beat the heck out of anything that you could do with manipulating cells in Excel... It is definitely more coding, but better practice. I just posted this to show you how I'd go about fixing YOUR code to make it more efficient if you did want to make the changes on the spreadsheet itself...